# JSON.parse vs custom for loop to deep clone js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I use backbone js.
After lot of reading about deep cloning a js collection (a backbone collection in my case). I'm confused between choosing between two shortlisted options.

myBBCollection is the source collection containing 'MyModel' models.

**Approach 1 (Use :JSON.parse)**

```
myTargetColl = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myBBCollection));
```

**Approach 2 (Use :forEach loop)**

```
myBBCollection.forEach(function(result){
    myTargetColl.push(new MyModel(result.toJSON()))
});
```

My question is about efficiency/coding standards. Which approach will be better over another?

P.S. I don't want to use .clone() function because it gives shallow copy.

Comment: Whats wrong about using Collection.clone? http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-clone

Comment: If a model's property is modified, it gets reflected in the corresponding model of cloned Collection.